# How to overwrite blob if exists in destination

Tags: c#, azure, copy, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Am using `TransferManager` to copy blobs from one container to another.

```
CloudStorageAccount sourceStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(@"source storage account connection string");
CloudStorageAccount destStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(@"destination storage account connection string");

CloudBlobClient sourceBlobClient = sourceStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobClient destBlobClient = destStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var sourceContainer = sourceBlobClient.GetContainerReference("sourceContainer");
var destContainer = destBlobClient.GetContainerReference("destContainer");

CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("copy.txt");
CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("copy.txt");

TransferManager.CopyAsync(sourceBlob, targetBlob, true).Wait();
```

But when the file exists in destination it throws error stating

> "Skiped file
>   \"https://sourceabcd.blob.core.windows.net/sourcecontainer/test1.txt\"
>   because target
>   \"https://sourceabcd.blob.core.windows.net/destcontainer/test1.txt\"
>   already exists."}  System.Exception
>   {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferSkippedException

Is there a option to overwrite the file if exists in destination ?

Comment: @Curiousdev I don't want that, am more specifically looking for option in `Azure Data Movement`.

Comment: Yes  i just read it i was wrong as you're using TransferManager to copy from one container to another...

Comment: Did you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41043925/7073340)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you're getting exception from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/lib/TransferManager.cs#L1327)

i think what you can do is something like below

```
TransferContext transferContext = new SingleTransferContext();
transferContext.ShouldOverwriteCallbackAsync = TransferContext.ForceOverwrite;
TransferManager.CopyAsync(sourceBlob, targetBlob, true,null,transferContext).Wait();
```

I don't have much idea about it but i found some test cases on github [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/test/DMLibTest/Cases/OverwriteTest.cs#L250)

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: @Curiousdev  I did the same and its working with CopyMethod.SyncCopy but failed with CopyMethod.ServiceSideSyncCopy with exception "level": "ERROR", "logger": "DataStoreCopyWorkflow", "exception": "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferException: The transfer failed.\r\n ---> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: Blob operation is not supported.\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers